# How can I express list comprehension in terms of higher order functions?

Tags: haskell

This program has the aim of using a higher-order function to represent a list comprehension, where it takes a function `(a -> b)` and filter p: `(a -> Bool)` and a list: `[Int]` to produce a list. However, a series of errors occur:

1. Couldn't match expected type `Bool -> [Int]` with actual type `[b0]`
2. The function `map` is applied to three arguments, but its type `(a1 -> b0) -> [a1] -> [b0]` has only two. `listcomprehension f p xs = map f filter(p xs)`
3. Couldn't match expected type `a1 -> b0` with actual type `(a, b)`
4. Couldn't match expected type `[a1]` with actual type `(a0 -> Bool) -> [a0] -> [a0]`.

`listcomprehension :: (a -> b) -> (a -> Bool) -> [Int] -> [Int]
 listcomprehension f p xs = map f filter(p xs)`

I have tried a different approach where I wrote:

```
listcomprehension :: (a -> b) -> [Int] -> [Int]
listcomprehension f xs = map f filter(p xs)
```

The error in the second solution is that p is not in scope. This leads to a dilemma of whether or not to add p as either way it results in an error, the question is how to include p as a parameter in the function?

Comment: `(a,b)` is not a function. `(a -> b)` is a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> where it takes a function `(a,b)`.

`(a, b)` is *not* a function. `(a, b)` is a 2-tuple, for a function, you need to rewrite this to `a -> b`.

Since you only work with a list of `Int`s, you furthermore can not use `a -> b` as a mapping function, and `a -> Bool` as a filtering function. These functions should be `f :: Int -> Int` and `p :: Int -> Bool`

You furthermore use the brackets the wrong way. In order to let this work, it should be:

```
listcomprehension :: (Int -> Int) -> (Int -> Bool) -> [Int] -> [Int]
listcomprehension f xs = map f (filter p xs)
```

or we can generalize this function further to:

```
listcomprehension :: (a -> b) -> (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [b]
listcomprehension f xs = map f (filter p xs)
```

The above is however not a list comprehension expression. You can implement such list comprehension expression with:

```
listcomprehension :: (a -> b) -> (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [b]
listcomprehension f xs = [f x | x <- xs, p x]
```